# List of Characters are Expanded in Quotation Marks (Singe/Double)

Tags: powershell

What are the character sets that need attention in both single/double quotation marks? Do we have a list for this?

**Simple example:**

```
$test1 = "hello {{0}}" -f "world"
--------
$unexpectedoutput = hello {0}
$expectedOutput   = hello {world}
```

```
$test2 = 'hello not good {0} }' -f "world"
--------
$unexpectedoutput = Error formatting a string...
$expectedOutput   = hello not good world }
```

it may be a simple example and it may have been mentioned many times but there is no regular list for these.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with single vs double quotes - this is simply [the behavior of `string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0#how-do-i-include-literal-braces--and--in-the-result-string), which is what `-f` maps to under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer:

To **`-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)** and the **[`System.String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Format) .NET method** that underlies it,  **`{` and `}` are *metacharacters***, because they're used to enclose the placeholders in the format string (e.g. `{0}`)

Therefore, ***verbatim* use of `{` and `}` in a format string requires *escaping*, namely as `{{` and `}}` respectively**.

The choice of PowerShell string-literal form (`"..."` vs. `'...'`) in your examples is *incidental* to your commands: in PowerShell string literals, `{` and `}` *aren't* special.

- However, for conceptual clarity it is better to use [verbatim (single-quoted) strings (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) rather than [expandable (double-quoted) strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) as format strings, to avoid a potentially confusing mix of up-front string interpolation and later placeholder substitution via `-f`.

---

Therefore, to make your commands work, use the following:

```bash
# Use {{ and }} to enclose placeholder {0} in verbatim { and }
'hello {{{0}}}' -f 'world'

# Use }} to result in a verbatim }
'hello not good {0} }}' -f 'world'
```

Note that an *error* occurs if stray (unescaped) `{` and `}` instances that aren't part of a well-formed placeholder specification (such as `{0}`) are encountered, such as in your
`'hello not good {0} }' -f 'world'` command.

---

To answer the question posed in the *title*: **What characters have special meaning in PowerShell string literals?**

- In [*verbatim*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) strings (`'...'`) *no* characters have special meaning; the only exception is `'` itself, which must be escaped as `''` in order to be embedded.
- In [*expandable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) strings (`"..."`), the following characters have special meaning:

  - `$`, if followed by a variable name (e.g. `"$HOME"`) or a sub-expression enclosed in `(...)` (e.g.`"$(Get-Date)"`)
  - `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, which is PowerShell's *escape character*, which serves two purposes:

    - Either: It initiates an *escape sequence* known to PowerShell - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.
    - Or: It *escapes* what would otherwise be a special character, notably `$` and `` ` `` itself, as well as an embedded `"` (an alternative to `` `" `` is to use `""`).

Note:

- Both types of string literals have [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) variants (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@` and `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) - if you use them, you do *not* need to escape embedded `'` and `"` characters.

Comment: Is there any automation for this?, for example I will give my whole powershell script, then I run whole code via power.exe ... I think heredoc is not usable for this right? Because in heredoc string single quotate is a problem scenario like this... My whole long script converted in single line then I can run my code inside powershell.exe <my-whole-command>

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I encourage you to create a new question post focused on your follow-up question.